# Yii loginRequired method malfunctions when using Rights module

Tags: php, yii

I try to `redirect` the user to the `login` page when he tryes to query the db using a `ajax` call and the `session has expired`, all this when using the `rights` module;

I searched within all the project for `403` and `loginRequired` and put a `die` function where text has been found, but i cant find the execution path in order to see why the `loginRequired` does not trigger;

I am using a `gridView` and i am using a `filter` to sort some data, while the `session` is expired;

I get a `error 403: login needed`

Does anyone know how to redirect the user in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Try this hint.

1st add this to your config:

```
    ...
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(          
        ...
        'loginRequiredAjaxResponse' => 'YII_LOGIN_REQUIRED',
        ...
    ),
    ...
```

Then in your view (layout) add:

```
<?php
    if (Yii::app()->components['user']->loginRequiredAjaxResponse){
        Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('ajaxLoginRequired', '
            jQuery("body").ajaxComplete(
                function(event, request, options) {
                    if (request.responseText == "'.Yii::app()->components['user']->loginRequiredAjaxResponse.'") {
                        window.location.href = "/login";
                    }
                }
            );
        ');
    }
?>
```

Should work. This will watch for ajax response, and if it equal to `loginRequiredAjaxResponse` will redirect to your login url.

It will work on yii>1.1.9. Also you can use not only `ajaxComplete` event to prevent errors, maybe `ajaxSuccess` will fit more.

Answer won't fit comment, so addition. Lets watch CWebUser implementation:

```
public function loginRequired()
    {
        $app=Yii::app();
        $request=$app->getRequest();

        if(!$request->getIsAjaxRequest())
        {
            ....
        }
        elseif(isset($this->loginRequiredAjaxResponse))
        {
            echo $this->loginRequiredAjaxResponse;
            Yii::app()->end();
        }

        throw new CHttpException(403,Yii::t('yii','Login Required'));
    }
```

So as you can see if our request not ajax - we simply redirect to login url, otherwise if in user component config set `loginRequiredAjaxResponse` we echo it and end app.
Login required exception invoked if both if's failed. I suppose that you have this message in your response with error page rendered?

Another problem can occure if you use custom User class and rewrite `loginRequired()` function.

And code above works in my projects, i use user+rights modules stack.

Comment: i did tryed those options; but they work only when you dont use the rights module and modules, like admin and client

Comment: I found the flow; the rights module, uses a error method within a module default controller to catch errors; this method is triggered before loginRequired

Comment: There is no flow. `if( $user->isGuest===true )
   $user->loginRequired();
  else
   throw new CHttpException(403, $message);` I suppose it's here. After session timeout user must be logged out, so his role will be guest.

Comment: Being a newbie, could not understand how I can use loginRequiredAjaxResponse to handle ajax session timeout.

Answer (score 0):

cgridview has a function afterAjaxUpdate that runs after an update has been done. Have you tried using that one to redirect them if a 403 response is received?

There is also ajaxUpdateError http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#ajaxUpdateError-detail (probably this is the one you should use) that you might use in the same way, when a 403 response is received, redirect them from javascript to the login page.